# How can I differentiate anonymous in Push

Tags: marketing-cloud, reporting, mobilepush, push

I would like to differentiate the anonymous users from the non-anonymous in Push. Is there a way to access that data? I see there is no Data Views but three reports in which I don't see how I can retrieve this information.

- Push Account Summary
- Push Message Detail
- Push Message Summary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Audience segmentation can be easily done with the use of `Tags`, `Attributes` and/or `ContactKey`.

Personalization can also be completed using AmpScript.  You could, for instance, say, "Welcome!" (for a contact without a "firstName" attribute set) or "Welcome, Bill!" (if the "firstName" is known.)

You have access to these, and other fields in Audience Builder's MobilePush Demographics.

Comment: Thanks.Is there the possibility of having different contacts with the same Device ID? Or once an anonymous contact registers and provides its data, does MC automatically merge with the initial data of the anonymous contact?

Comment: Devices are reconciled via ContactKey.  A "new" contact is created when a new ContactKey is provided and the device is disassociated from the anonymous contact.

Comment: So, the Device ID is disassociated from the anonymous, but the anonymous still remains as contact with no channel associated or dissapear directly ?